# Start and stop a function on Nodejs server from client through Socket io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

```
-----------------------------client socket ----------------------  
 $(document).ready(function () {
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8282');
  $('#stopbtn').click(function(){
    socket.emit('RandomStatus',{message:'stop'});
  })
  $('#startbtn').click(function(){
    socket.emit('RandomStatus',{message:'start'});
  })
});
```

----------------------------------Nodejs server --------------------

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(8282));
io.set('log level', 1);
var randomizerjson = require('./randomizerjson');
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var intervalId;
    socket.on('RandomStatus', function (data) {
        var status = data.message;
        if(status=='start'){
                 //random data after 700 milisecond and send
                intervalId= setInterval(function () {
                var randomData = randomizerjson.getRandomData1();
                //send random data somewhere
                io.sockets.emit('dataSet', randomData);
            }, 700);
        }
        if(status=='stop'){
            clearInterval(intervalId); 
        }

    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('user disconnect');
    });
});
```

When I click start button, I can send random data. But when I click stop button, I can not clearInterval to stop sending random data.
I want to stop sending random data when I receive 'stop' message, but that's not working. Can anyone help me and tell me why?

Comment: Can you tell us what you tryed and what you obtained ? (just asking "please debug my code" usually does not work on this website !)

Comment: With your code it's possible that multiple interval loops are started (by sending the `start` message multiple times before sending the `stop` message). The `stop` message will only clear the last one, the others will continue. Are you sure your problem isn't caused by that?